# Add multiple attributes to a child in SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml

I want to add multiple attributes to a child in `SimpleXMLElement` so it will look like this:

```
<data>
    <photo>
        <file size="3309519" size="JPG">P1270081</file>
    </photo>
</data>
```

As it is right now in my code, I can only add one attribute per child as the code below shows.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<data/>');

$photo = $xml->addChild('photo');
$photo->addChild('file', 'P1270081')->addAttribute('size', '3309519');
$photo->addChild('uploaded', '2013-09-01 15:23:10')->addAttribute('by', 'edgren');
```

If I change the third line to `$photo->addChild('file', 'P1270081')->addAttribute('size', '3309519')->addAttribute('type', 'JPG');` I'm getting this error message:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function addAttribute() on a non-object in ...`

I am new to creating XML files on the fly with SimpleXMLElement so I don't know how I shall fix this issue. What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`addAttribute` returns `void`. If you want to add more attributes you have to something like this:

```
$file = $photo->addChild('file', 'P1270081');
$file->addAttribute('size', '3309519');
$file->addAttribute('type', 'JPG');
```

Comment: Many thanks for your correct answer! I'll accept it as an answer as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 0):

**$photo->addChild(..)**  // returns the created XML component .. and you can chain a action(one) directly one it.
But  **addAttribute(..)**  returns nothing .. so you get an error if you try to chain event after it.

```
$photo = $xml->addChild('photo');
$photo->addChild('file', 'P1270081')->addAttribute('size', '3309519');
$theNewChild = $photo->addChild('uploaded', '2013-09-01 15:23:10')

$theNewChild ->addAttribute('by', 'edgren');
$theNewChild ->addAttribute('type', 'JPG');
```